# From where can I get Fridge Magnet having SFF.SE logo printed on it?

Tags: support, feature-request

I am enjoying [my Batman Fridge Magnet](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/198?m=36408115#36408115) and I want a similar circular Fridge Magnet having SFF.SE logo printed on it (which would be fantastic as SFF.SE logo is also circular). From where can I get it?

The logo should be IP of Stack Exchange, so I doubt I'll be able to find it on Amazon or eBay because of legal issues. Can SE guys put it on sell?

**Update:**
I think problem's been solved. Previously, I was unable to find a printing service which could print on a circular magnet. Finally, I found it: http://www.picsquare.com/custom/magnet

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because "shopping" questions are off-topic

Comment: @Valorum on meta too? When related to SFF.SE as well? Looks to me that this question is similar to the one about moderator cards.

Comment: @Gallifreyan - Ultimately this question is "where can I get a magnet printed?" the SFF angle is incidental.

Answer (score 2):

*I Am Not A Lawyer*, but if you download a high-res version of the logo and take it down to your local printshop, as long as it's just for personal use on your own fridge, you probably should be fine.

For completeness' sake, here's [the official SE trademark guidance](https://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance).

Comment: Many print shops will not print anything they suspect that the customer does not have legal rights to.

Comment: Also, SE would be unhappy if they found out, per their copyright & trademark guidelines: "Do not use any other artwork from our network without explicit permission."

Comment: You can also print it (or have it printed) on sticker paper and stick it to a magnetic sheet (available at many hardware stores), then cut it out. People do this for bumper stickers, especially campaign stickers.